# Shifting wrap fig upward

Tags: wrapfigure

I'm trying to have a tikzpicture diagram side by side with the question, as seen in this image:
[image]

However, as seen in the image, the wrapfig doesn't really align well with the first line of the paragraph. Is there a way to shift the diagram up? I tried using \vspace{-1em} but to no avail.

Here is the corresponding latex code:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0pt}
\centering
%\vspace{-1em} (doesn't really do anything)
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (4,2) arc (60:180:2);
\draw (4,2) arc (300:180:2);
\draw (3,0.2679491924311226) arc (0:120:2);
\draw (3,0.2679491924311226) arc (240:120:2);
\draw (1,3.7320508075688785) arc (60:-60:2);
\draw (3,3.7320508075688785) arc (360:240:2);
\draw (0,3.7320508075688785)-- (4,3.7320508075688785);
\draw (4,3.7320508075688785)-- (4,0.2679491924311228);
\draw (4,0.2679491924311228)-- (0,0.2679491924311226);
\draw (0,0.2679491924311226)-- (0,3.732050807568877);
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw (1,2) node {$A$};
\draw (1.5,2.9) node {$B$};
\draw (2.5,2.9) node {$C$};
\draw (3,2) node {$D$};
\draw (2.5,1.2) node {$E$};
\draw (1.5,1.2) node {$F$};
\draw (-0.2,3.9) node {$P$};
\draw (4.2,3.9) node {$Q$};
\draw (4.2,0.1) node {$R$};
\draw (-0.2,0.1) node {$S$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}

\begin{problem}
Consider the following diagram, where six petaled rosette (labelled with $A$ to $F$) is formed using unit circles enclosed by the rectangle $PQRS$.\\
Determine
\begin{equation*}
x=\frac{|A|+|B|+|C|+|D|+|E|+|F|}{|PQRS|}.
\end{equation*}
\end{problem}
```

The 'problem' environment is defined as below:

```
\newcounter{problem}[section]
\newenvironment{problem}[1][]{\refstepcounter{problem}\par\medskip
\noindent \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{Problem~\theproblem}\space #1 \rmfamily}}{\medskip}
```

I used the packages warpfig and tikz to achieve the original layout.

Would appreciate any help - thank you!

Comment: you have the answer, commented out `\vspace{-1em} (doesn't really do anything)`   but you have set the width of the figure to 0pt??? if that doesn't work, please provide a complete small example document (no disconnected fragments) that demonsrtates the problem

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried adjusting the 0pt to a value that is larger than the figure's width (~4.5cm) and it seemed to align itself with the first line. Problem solved and thanks for pointing it out

Comment: If I have learned something from many years of tex'ing, it's to never use `warpfig` unless you absolutely must. Also, delay using `warpfig` until the latest moment. And actually, if you re-think your figure placement, you can go without, which is probably the best way anyway. You loose much of "stability" of your document with `warpfig`, which is especially important at the early stages. (With apologies to `warpfig` authors, I really tried to live it in that one paper, I really tried. The amount of grey hair it gave to me is absolutely unproportional to the benefit.)

Answer (score 0):

See, if the following is what you after:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, demo]{article} 
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{lipsum}  


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

    \begin{wrapfigure}[12]{R}{50mm}  % <--- manual centering of this wrapfigure
    \centering
    \small
    \vspace{-0.6\baselineskip}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
every label/.style = {inner sep=1pt}
                    ]
\node (s) [draw, minimum size=40mm, inner sep=0pt,
           label= 45:$Q$,
           label=135:$P$,
           label=225:$S$,
           label=315:$R$] {};

    \foreach \i/\j in {0/4,60/5,120/5,180/4,240/5,300/5}
{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\m}{sqrt(\j)}
\draw[rotate around={\i:(0,0)}]
        (0,0)   arc (120:60:\m) arc (-60:-120:\m);
}
    \foreach \i/\j in {0/D,60/C,120/B,180/A,240/E,300/D}
\path (\i:1) node {$\j$};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[2-6]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: you not provide MWE (Minimal Working Example, which would reproduce your problem, so n above suggestion is used dummy text generated by `lipsum` package.